# How to add my own built-in function to php source code?

Tags: php, html, c

I know php code can be rewritten in C. So just like a `strpos()` function, I want to add my own **built-in function** (lets assume a function name `vinod`) in **php source code**. Is this possible? If yes then let me know the procedure.

Sample function pseudo-code: my function will return **str** in a heading tag1.

```
vinod($str)
{
    return <h1>$str</h1>;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to extend the PHP parser? Just write you own functions in PHP...

Comment: Just why? 1. You would need to write your code in C 2. You would need to re-compile the source code and it would be a HUGE amount of work to add/update all entries in the source code that your function works! Then you can also write your own program language...

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: Sara's book is a bit out of date now, but it's still the definitive guide to editing the PHP core - http://www.amazon.com/Extending-Embedding-PHP-Sara-Golemon/dp/067232704X

Comment: @VinodJakhar ^ Seems like that's your job. How should you be able to do your job if we have to code for you?

Comment: @Rizier123, friend I just wants some help. I am not asking you to do my job.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a PHP C extension, to add your custom C functions to be available as PHP native functions see below:

1. [Why write your own extension?](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/20/1/0)
2. [How do I build my first PHP extension in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250412/how-do-i-build-my-first-php-extension-in-c-on-linux-gcc)
3. [Writing PHP C extensions](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/)
4. [A C++ library for developing PHP extensions](http://www.php-cpp.com/)